# Qt resource images not visbile

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, qt4

I'm using Visual Studio 2008 with Qt Designer (Qt 4.8) and added my images to the resources:

```
<resource root>
    Images
        Image.gif
```

In Qt Designer QGraphicsView:

```
border-image: url(:/Images/Image.gif);
```

The files are stored binary in qrc_Program.cpp and should be compiled to the executable?!

-> the image is visible in designer but if I start the release program on another PC I can't see it!

**Update:**

I added my plugins directory to the application dir path: (main.cpp)

```
QApplication a(argc, argv); 
a.addLibraryPath(a.applicationDirPath() + "/plugins");
```

after that I print out the supported image formats with `QImageReader::supportedImageFormats()` and on the target machine I only have the default formats like png, bmp..., but on my PC I see gif, png and all others. Any help would be very appreciated!

What is wrong here?

Comment: Did you deployed the _imageformats_ with _qgif.dll_ in it?

Comment: @Zlatomir Ok, I found this libs. Do you mean copy this files to the executable folder? (tried it and still no success)

Comment: You should put those libs into the _imageformats_ directory beside your executable.

Comment: `path_to_your_app/imageformats/qgif.dll`

Comment: @thuga Update information added

Comment: `path_to_your_app/imageformats/qgif.dll` != `path_to_your_app/plugins/imageformats/qgif.dll`

Comment: @thuga: Yes I know, but that makes no difference and in fact I do the same because I add app path + plugins (e.g. folder structure: c:\Prg\plugins\imageformats\qgif4.dll) to the library path! Any other ideas? Thx

Comment: Sorry, I misread your code. It looks like it should work. I will try to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Works fine on my end. I used [`QCoreApplication::setLibraryPaths`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#setLibraryPaths) instead of `QCoreApplication::addLibraryPath` to clear the old paths, but it shouldn't matter.

Comment: @thuga weird. I also tried to set the HKCU\Environment\Path but no success :-( (workaround: convert all graphics to png)

Comment: Are you sure you're putting the correct `.dll` files in the `imageformats` directory?

Comment: @thuga yes, I'm sure. Any other files from Qt needed? (I only have QtCore4.dll and QtGui4.dll in the executable folder)